# How can I customize the style of a discretization of a Region?

Tags: graphics, regions

**This works as expected:**

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[Triangle[], Rectangle[{0.5, 0}, {1, 1}]]]
```

[image: Union of triangle and rectangle]

Now, suppose I want to change the fill color to green and the edge color to red. How would I do that?

*(I tried using RegionPlot, but that didn't work)*

Comment: This is on 11.0, by the way.

Comment: It's interesting that you say that `RegionPlot[RegionUnion[..]]` works as expected, since as far as I can tell, nowhere in the documentation does it say that such a thing is supported.

Comment: @CarlWoll If there were documentation on that usage, that is how I would expect it to function. I read about using `RegionPlot[]` that way in a Q here (can't remember which question, unfortunately). In any case, you bring up an interesting point. When I try `RegionPlot[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[Triangle[], Rectangle[{0.9, 0}, {1, 1}]]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`, I get all sorts of errors. Does this mean that `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[]` doesn't give me a legitimate region to plot with `RegionPlot`?

Comment: Why do you want to use `RegionPlot` in this way? Is it just so that there are ticks? Is it because you need a `Graphics` object?

Comment: The latter. I can view the region with `Region[RegionUnion[Triangle[], Rectangle[{0.5, 0}, {1, 1}]]]`, but I'm trying to control border and fill color. I don't really need ticks or a frame, and I'd be happy to avoid `RegionPlot[]` altogether as it seems a lot slower than working with graphics objects. Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  RegionUnion[Triangle[], Rectangle[{0.5, 0}, {1, 1}]], 
  BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green, EdgeColor -> Red}] `?

Comment: @CarlWoll That's exactly the functionality I need to avoid `RegionPlot`! Thanks! Now, what to do about the question. Should I close/delete it because it's asking about an unsupported use of `RegionPlot`? If not, is it answerable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion) takes most of the options available to [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics):

```
Complement[
    Options[Graphics][[All, 1]],
    Options[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion][[All, 1]]
]
```

> {ColorOutput, ContentSelectable, CoordinatesToolOptions, FormatType, \
>   ImageSizeRaw, PreserveImageOptions}

This means, that you should be able to use [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) options to control the appearance of the discretization. Rather than just giving you the options to use, I will show you how to find out what options are available for this purpose. The box form of [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) is [`GraphicsBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsBox), and the options for [`GraphicsBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsBox) are:

```
Options[GraphicsBox]
```

> {AlignmentPoint -> Center, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False, 
>    AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, Automatic}, AxesStyle -> {}, 
>    Background -> None, BaseStyle -> {}, BaselinePosition -> Automatic, 
>    ColorOutput -> Automatic, ContentSelectable -> Automatic, 
>    CoordinatesToolOptions :> Automatic, DefaultAxesStyle -> "GraphicsAxes", 
>    DefaultBaseStyle -> "Graphics", DefaultFrameStyle -> "GraphicsFrame", 
>    DefaultFrameTicksStyle -> "GraphicsFrameTicks", 
>    DefaultGridLinesStyle -> "GraphicsGridLines", 
>    DefaultLabelStyle -> "GraphicsLabel", DefaultTicksStyle -> "GraphicsTicks", 
>    Epilog -> {}, FormatType -> TraditionalForm, Frame -> False, 
>    FrameLabel -> None, FrameStyle -> {}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
>    FrameTicksStyle -> {}, GridLines -> None, GridLinesStyle -> {}, 
>    ImageMargins -> 0., ImageMarkers -> None, ImagePadding -> All, 
>    ImageSize -> Automatic, ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, 
>    ImageSizeRules -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {}, Method -> {}, 
>    PlotLabel -> None, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
>    PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, PlotRegion -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
>    PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, Prolog -> {}, RotateLabel -> True, 
>    Ticks -> Automatic, TicksStyle -> {}}

In particular, note the [`DefaultBaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultBaseStyle) option:

```
Options[GraphicsBox, DefaultBaseStyle]
```

> {DefaultBaseStyle -> "Graphics"}

The [`DefaultBaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultBaseStyle) points to the style `"Graphics"`. This style has the following settings:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics"}]
```

> {CellMargins -> {{4, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}, 
>    CellGroupingRules -> "GraphicsGrouping", StripStyleOnPaste -> False, 
>    PageBreakWithin -> False, GeneratedCell -> True, CellAutoOverwrite -> True, 
>    ShowCellLabel -> False, DefaultFormatType -> DefaultOutputFormatType, 
>    ContextMenu -> {MenuItem["Cu&t Graphics Selection", "Cut"], 
>      MenuItem["&Copy Graphics Selection", "Copy"], 
>      MenuItem["&Paste into Graphic", FrontEnd`Paste[After]], Delimiter, 
>      MenuItem["&Drawing Tools", 
>       FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookOpen[
>          FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["DrawingTools.nb", 
>           "PrivatePathsSystemResources"]]}]], 
>      MenuItem["&Get Coordinates", 
>       FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["GetCoordinates"]]], Delimiter, 
>      MenuItem["G&roup", "Group"], MenuItem["&Ungroup", "Ungroup"], Delimiter, 
>      MenuItem["Move to &Front", "MoveToFront"], 
>      MenuItem["Move to &Back", "MoveToBack"], 
>      MenuItem["Move For&ward", "MoveForward"], 
>      MenuItem["Move Bac&kward", "MoveBackward"]}, 
>    "AutoStyleOptionsHighlightMisspelledWords" -> False, 
>    LanguageCategory -> "NaturalLanguage", FormatType -> StandardForm, 
>    ShowStringCharacters -> False, NumberMarks -> False, 
>    CounterIncrements -> "Graphics", 
>    ImageMargins -> {{43, Inherited}, {Inherited, 0}}, Arrowheads -> 0.04, 
>    Dashing -> None, CapForm -> "Square", JoinForm -> {"Miter", 3.25}, 
>    LineColor -> GrayLevel[0], LineOpacity -> 1, EdgeColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    EdgeOpacity -> 1, EdgeThickness -> Medium, EdgeDashing -> None, 
>    EdgeCapForm -> "Square", EdgeJoinForm -> {"Miter", 3.25}, 
>    FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    FrontFaceOpacity -> 1, BackFaceOpacity -> 1, GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    PointSize -> Absolute[3], Thickness -> Medium, Opacity -> 1, 
>    DrawEdges -> False, StyleMenuListing -> None, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
>    FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> "Plain", FontColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    FontOpacity -> 1}

You see options controlling [`LineColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineColor), [`EdgeColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeColor), etc., and you can play with changing these settings to see what their effects are. To change the fill color and the edge color of your discretization, you could use:

```
BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green, EdgeColor -> Red, EdgeThickness -> .02}
```

Using this [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle) in your discretization produces:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    RegionUnion[Triangle[], Rectangle[{0.5, 0}, {1, 1}]],
    BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green, EdgeColor -> Red, EdgeThickness -> .02}
]
```

[image]

Comment: "I will show you how to find out what options are available for this purpose." Invaluable to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the option [`MeshCellStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellStyle.html).

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  RegionUnion[Triangle[], Rectangle[{0.5, 0}, {1, 1}]], 
  MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Directive[Thick, Red], 2 -> Green}
]
```

[image]